# Why does Firefox remove the "close tab button" when you have more than n tabs open unless you focus on the tab?

Tags: design-patterns, tabs, browser, firefox

The origin of this question is that I've tried to find a way to override the behaviour of Firefox which removes the *close tab button* of unfocused tabs as the number of tabs rises, with no luck.

My issue is that Firefox removes the button to close a tab when the tab bar amount rises to (in my environment) 14 tabs and above.

[image]

This is a behaviour that, as far as I'm concerned, is a violation both to consistency and shortcut accessibility, both listed in [Schneiderman's Eight Golden Rules](http://faculty.washington.edu/jtenenbg/courses/360/f04/sessions/schneidermanGoldenRules.html), leading to a compromising of the overall UX of the application.

To strengthen my case I have Chrome as a reference which doesn't have that behaviour.

[image]

And in my meaning this is the appropriate way, and that Firefox in their approach are violating a number of usability rules.

I see Mozilla's reasoning behind it, they fear users will get annoyed if they accidentally close a tab that they intend to focus. However, is this enough of a big reason to violate consistency and shortcut pattern?

**EDIT:** [dnbrv](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/10478/dnbrv) informed me that Opera uses the same approach as Firefox. And as I took a look at Internet Explorer I saw that they don't use shortcuts at all for tabs that aren't focused. I guess that works in a consistency aspect but it's terrible for shortcut accessibility. Another reason to add to the heap of why I chose not to use ie.

Comment: AFAIK, Opera behaves the same way.

Comment: @dnbrv Interesting. I only had Chrome as a reference since Chrome and FF are the only browsers I commonly use.

Comment: [Note I use Chrome 12] I prefer having the tab close button visible on every tab as it makes it easier to target with the mouse but then again I use the scroll wheel to switch tabs (which Chrome only supports on Linux and I get annoyed when I use browsers that don't support it)

Comment: Using the scroll wheel to switch tabs sounds like a neat feature. And I'm a bit on the same playing field as you, I use Ctrl+tab and Ctrl+shift+tab to switch tabs, never really switch tabs through direct manipulation. Which I guess is one reason why I never get the problem of accidentally closing a tab.

Comment: I suspect they remove it so that more of the title can be displayed. However, you points about it violating various "rules" are valid.

Comment: @ChrisF that does sound like a legitimate reasoning behind it. However, on my environment, the button is removed when there are about 15 characters left to display the "tab name". And that seems like more than enough to distinguish which tab it is, especially since it's +icon.

Comment: Chrome definitely does this as well, although its threshold for hiding the X seems to be much higher.

Comment: Mozilla used to publish usability studies, didn't they?  I can't seem to find anything recent...

Comment: Chrome DOES do this, it's threshold is just higher than Firefox's. In fact, all browsers do this, period, though many browsers just hide the X on all tabs that aren't focused at all times.

Comment: You should be using a middle mousebutton click to close tabs anyway.

Comment: @Barfieldmv, or `Ctrl + w`

Comment: @Barfieldmv. Right on, brother! People should learn keyboard/mouse shortcuts for software that they spend half their life using.

Comment: Firefox _used_ to have the close button visible on all tabs by default.  It was changed for usability, as mentioned in the answers below.  (Although that was only for a short period between the current time and the previous era, where there was one close button to the right of all the tabs, which I still greatly prefer)

Comment: @Barfieldmv actually clicking the middle mouse button when its a scroll wheel is much harder than clicking either of the other mouse buttons and even using 3rd mouse button emulation (which I should re-enable) via clicking both the left and right at the same time is easier than clicking a scroll wheel

Comment: @DanD. My finger resting position is actually on top of the scroll wheel for easy scrolling and closing of tabs :D

Comment: I don't click with the scroll wheel

Comment: This problem doesn't exist if you use tree-style tabs :) The list grows down *(like it should)* instead of horizontally

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft If you use a tree-style tab list, you are obviously using an extension so it should be their job to adjust the user controls for that.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the feature that the middle mouse button would close a tag. However I use the middle mouse button for opening up links in new tags religiously. And that this works for the browser action buttons (back, refresh, forward) is also a great feature.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Chrome does the same thing:

[image]

There are two reasons for this:

**It makes it hard to click close on accident**. This is easiest to note on the Chrome example, if every one of those super teeny tabs had an X, it would be *extremely* difficult to select a tab without closing it. **Prefer safe actions**. If you have a safe action and a risky action, the risky action should require more work to get to, that's exactly what browsers are doing here.

**It focuses on the tab content, not the interface**. I don't care that there's a close button on this tab. I care *what the tab is*. If you're displaying the interface and not the content, you're doing it wrong. When looking at not-focused tabs, chances are I need to know *what it is* moreso than I need to know how I can immediately close that tab.

You point to Schiedman's rules but you seem to be forgetting #6: Easy reversal of actions. Shortcuts are still intact, and the internal locus of control is intact, so I don't think the "rules" argument is very valid. No, it's not entirely consistent, but consistency which harms readability and usability is *not good consistency*.

There's also little violation of the "shortcuts" rule. If you're an advanced browser user, you can use middle click to close any tab instantly, which is much faster than targeting the red X even when it's here.

It's also important to note that *every single popular browser*, including IE and Dolphin and Mobile Safari do this in some way (so it's it's a convention), some browsers simply never show the X on any tab that's not focused.

Comment: "focuses on the tab content, not the interface" is the critical piece I think.

Comment: Requoting for truth: If you're displaying the interface and not the content, you're doing it wrong. +1[1tybillion]

Answer (score 10):

Maybe, maybe not, but **it is not "bad" because it violates a "rule".**

Rules don't *always* work in *all* situations.  One of the main reasons designers exist is to decide when rules ought to be broken, or what rules are *useful* in a given scenario.

For instance, there are (at least) two general "rules" (I prefer the terms *guidelines* or *patterns*, for the record) at play in this case:

1. Maintain consistency - users learn to predict patterns quickly, and you cause cognitive suffering when you break the pattern.
2. Don't clump controls too close together so it is easy to accidentally hit the wrong one.

When only a few tabs are open, guideline 2 doesn't much matter - there's lots of distance between controls.  As you add more tabs and distances shrink, guideline 2 becomes more of a concern.

As a thought experiment, imagine the tabs even more tightly packed - at some point, it would be completely *impossible* to fit the `tab close` control and the `tab select` adjacent to each other, and they would overlap - do you allow this to happen in the name of maintaining consistency?  (For that matter, aren't you committing consistency misdemeanors every time you shrink the tab width to fit more tabs?)

The real measure of whether this is a good design choice is **the effect on users**, and would be evident in user observation.

- Do Firefox users experience fewer accidental closes than Chrome users?
- Are Firefox users slower to close tabs than Chrome users?
- Do users generally prefer having the design prefer closing vs. switching tabs? (And at what threshold of tabs on the screen?)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Having the `[x]` appear at all times takes away from available screen real estate.

Note that when active, the SOF tab can only show `Newest '...`, but when I'm on another tab, I get just enough more context to know which "Newest"... (`Newest 'wpf' Questions`)

**Edit** (to respond to Golden Rules)

`shortcut accessibility`

`-> Ctrl + w`

Also, this helps solve **#5 Offer simple error handling**. This makes it **easier to click/focus without closing** it.  Firefox could also be **assuming** that a user who has **multiple tabs open** has them open **for a reason** (and the user don't want to close them). Whereas a user who only has 3 tabs open, only needs a small amount of tabs for their current context/task.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 2.0 introduced a number of refinements to its tabbed browsing UI. Among them was the addition of close buttons on tabs. The [browser.tabs.closeButtons](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.tabs.closeButtons) preference on about:config controls how they can be displayed on tabs.

Possible values and their effects:

0 - Display a close button on the active tab only

1 - Display close buttons on all tabs (Default)

2 - Don’t display any close buttons

3 - Display a single close button at the end of the tab strip (Firefox 1.x behavior)

Since the close button takes up 16 pixels’ worth of tab width, it can obscure the tab’s text if you have a lot of tabs open and the tab widths become narrow. As a compromise, the close buttons are only shown on background tabs if their width is equal to or greater than [browser.tabs.tabClipWidth](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.tabs.tabClipWidth)’s value.

The code to set the minimum tab width was moved to [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/custom-tab-width/).

Comment: Are you promoting your add-on? Your answer doesn't explain the OP's question.

Comment: If you compare the names, you'll find them quite different. So no, i am not promoting my add-on, dnbrv. Your comment does not explain an issue as i did actually answer the OP's questions. Furthermore, if anything, i dislike the author of the add-on as he is the one who removed the code in the first place. I'd also like to note that you appear to be plugging Opera, a browser unrelated to the question.

Comment: I "plugged" Opera because this is UX where conversations take place around *patterns*.

Comment: In that case the pattern appears to be that customization will be done via add-ons instead of a monolith of rules like in Opera.